# What are 3 possible situations in which static methods might be included in classes?

Tags: java, static, class, methods

I got this question for homework, and all I can think of is to return a subclass of an abstract superclass.

Thanks!

Comment: Static methods are dangerous, kid.

Comment: @GregS
I have two questions about it tonight and that's all of my homework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try looking at the existing Java APIs (eg: `java.lang` and `java.util`) to see where they use static methods.

Answer (score 1):

#### Factory methods

- That return a particular instance like in a Singleton: [`java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime())
- That return a subclass of a super class as you mentioned: [`java.util.Calendar.getInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance())
- That perform type conversion: [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))

#### Utility methods

- In a class that also has instance methods : [`java.lang.String.format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))
- In utility classes that are not meant to be instantiated at all: [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), [`java.lang.Math`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), [`java.util.Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Answer (score 0):

Generally methods which need not be tied to a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Factory methods.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget about using them to kick off the console applications we all had to write in cs101